# How can $\sin(2*\arcsin(3/5))$ be evaluated by hand?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

Although it is dandy enough to simply go on [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(2*arcsin(3%2F5))) to see that the answer is 24/25, I would like to learn how to prove that by hand, if possible. Unfortunately, [arcsin(3/5)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arcsin(3%2F5)) is a transcendental number, and it seems to go have endless digits.

Is there a way to evaluate sin(2*arcsin(3/5)) to be 24/25 without jumping into computer functions?

Comment: Given $\sin \alpha = 3/5$ find a way to calculate $\sin 2 \alpha$.

Comment: Of course there is

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle_formulae

Comment: Hint: $\sin(2x)=2\cos(x)\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's use a right triangle. The simple one, 3-4-5.

I can't draw a diagram since I suck at those, but let the angle $\theta$ be opposite of the side of length 3. So $\sin(\theta)=\frac{3}{5}$ and $\cos(\theta)=\frac{4}{5}.$ (This is actually derivable since $\cos^2\theta=1-\sin^2\theta=\frac{16}{25}.$ Note that this doesn't make $\cos\theta=-\frac{4}{5}$ thanks to arcsin's definition.)

Now, $\sin(2\theta)=2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)=2\cdot \frac{3}{5}\cdot \frac{4}{5}=\boxed{\frac{24}{25}}.$

Answer (score 2):

You can use the double angle formula to  write $$\begin{eqnarray}\sin(2\arcsin(3/5)) &=& 2\sin(\arcsin(3/5))\cos(\arcsin(3/5))\\ &=& 2\sin(\arcsin(3/5))\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\arcsin(3/5))}\end{eqnarray}$$

We have $\sin(\arcsin(3/5)) =3/5$, so can plug this in to get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}\\
\sin(2\arcsin(x))
&=2\sin(\arcsin(x))\cos(\arcsin(x))\\
&=2x\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\arcsin(x))}\\
&=2x\sqrt{1-x^2}\\
\end{array}
$

Putting $x = 3/5$,
since
$\sqrt{1-x^2} = 4/5$,
I get
$2\dfrac35 \dfrac45
=\dfrac{24}{25}
$.

Answer (score 1):

By formula $\sin x=2\sin x\cos x$ we write
$$\color{red}{\sin(2\arcsin\dfrac35)}=2\sin(\arcsin\dfrac35)\cos(\arcsin\dfrac35)$$
By formula $\cos x=\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$
$$\color{red}{\sin(2\arcsin\dfrac35)}=2\sin(\arcsin\dfrac35)\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\arcsin\dfrac35)}$$
But $\sin(\arcsin x)=x$ then
$$\color{red}{\sin(2\arcsin\dfrac35)}=2\dfrac35\sqrt{1-(\dfrac35)^2}$$
$$\color{red}{\sin(2\arcsin\dfrac35)}=2\dfrac35\sqrt{\dfrac{16}{25}}=\color{blue}{\dfrac{24}{25}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use $\sin(2x) =2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ and then $\cos(x)=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}$.

Answer (score 0):

for any $\theta$ we have
$$
\sin 2\theta = 2 \sin \theta\cos \theta
$$
if
$$
\theta = \arcsin \frac35
$$
then, trivially,
$$
\sin \theta = \frac35
$$
using
$$
\cos^2 \theta +\sin^2 \theta = 1
$$
can you compute $\cos \theta$ to finish off? (how do you interpret the fact that there are two possible values of $\cos \theta$?)